# Load code from .php file every few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to load code from sadrzaj.php every 3 seconds. This is my code:

```
<body onload="ima_sta_novo()">
<div id="sadrzaj">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ima_sta_novo(){
        $('#sadrzaj').load('sadrzaj.php');

    }
    setInterval(function(){ima_sta_novo()}, 3000);

</script>
```

But, it isn't loading anything. What am I doing wrong?

**SOLVED!
I suddenly forgot to include jQuery. I'm facedesking now! :D**

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you need a closing `<div>` tag.

Comment: This is jQuery - it would definitely pay to wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(...` and you can simply put `setInterval(ima_sta_novo, 3000);`

Comment: Oh thanks! I suddenly forgot to include jQuery. I'm facedesking now! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and have a look at the developer JavaScript console (press F12 in Chrome/Chromium) and see if the word "invoked" or any error messages happen:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sadrzaj"></div>

        <script>

            function setTimer() {
                setInterval(function(){
                    console.log('invoked');
                    $('#sadrzaj').load('sadrzaj.php');

                }, 3000);
            }


            $(document).ready(setTimer);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             setInterval(function (e) {
             $('#sadrzaj').load('sadrzaj.php');
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss div end tag in your html code,

In javascript the code is :

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
  ima_sta_novo();
}, 3000);
```

If you use jquery library, the code is :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   setInterval( function()
   {
      ima_sta_novo();
   }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with javascript

```
<body onload="ima_sta_novo();">
<div id="sadrzaj">
    </div>
    <script>
         function ima_sta_novo(){
        window.location.href = "sadzraj.php";
    }
    setInterval(function(){ima_sta_novo()}, 3000);

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Close the div

```
<div id="sadrzaj"></div>
```

seems all other things are ok..

**put an alert box inside** the javascript method **ima_sta_novo()** for checking

Answer (score -1):

Replace http://stackoverflow.com with the link to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com")},3000);
</script>
```

This way you completely reload the page if you don't mind reloading the page this is a easy way to go.